# Пропадает штриховка полигонов opengl

Tags: opengl, glut

```
Почему штриховка отображается только на первом объекте?
    void display()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        TWallElement t1 = TWallElement(5, 5, 300, 200);
        t1.MainWall(my);
        t1.Window(20, 20, 260, 160, 1, 2);

        TWallElement t2 = TWallElement(310, 5, 200, 200);
        t2.MainWall(my);
        t2.Window(20, 20, 160, 160, 1, 1);

        glFlush();
    }
    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowSize(W, H);
        glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
        glutCreateWindow("123");
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glutDisplayFunc(display); 
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0f, W, H, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
```

В этом участке включаю штриховку для основной стены(т.е. первой)

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(MainWall_x0, MainWall_y0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.f);
    //Рисуем стенку и накладываем штрихи
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE); // Включаем штриховку 
    glPolygonStipple(cross); // Задаем узор 
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(Main_size_x, 0);
    glVertex2f(Main_size_x, Main_size_y);
    glVertex2f(0, Main_size_y);
    glEnd();

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glLineWidth(LineWidth);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(Main_size_x, 0);
    glVertex2f(Main_size_x, Main_size_y);
    glVertex2f(0, Main_size_y);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);//Выключаем штриховку
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть у кого-то какие-то идеи???

Comment: Неактуально...!